# Can we use he or she twice in a sentence

Tags: grammar

Eg : He said that he will perform the steps which I asked him to do.

Comment: Never, ever, ever say: *He or she said that he or she will perform the steps I asked him or her to do.* Just don't.

Comment: There are no rules on frequency of use of words in English sentences.  Your goal is unambiguous conveyance of information.  whether multiple uses of *he* ( or *she*) in a sentence- especially if those uses refer to different people- accomplishes that depends on context.   *”He told me he said he would do it before he went to work.”*  Who’s telling whom what?

Comment: What makes you think that you cannot use a pronoun more than once in a sentence? Why only _he_ or _she_? How about, “I said that I will perform the tasks I was asked to do”?

Comment: There are no rules about that. It depends entirely on the context and the rest of the wording of the sentence.

*He or she said that he or she will perform the steps I asked him or her to do* seems rather a perverse distraction.

*He said that he will perform the steps (which) I asked him to (do)* is just fine.

What made you think otherwise, please?